# Benefits of L0 compressed sensing

Tags: fitting, overfitting

Suppose we have an very efficient way to perform L0 norm compressed vs L1 norm compressed sensing. Specifically: L0 norm compressed sensing is:

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad {x^T}Qx + {b^T}x + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_0}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

while L1 norm compressed sensing:

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad {x^T}Qx + {b^T}x + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_1}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

Should we almost always use the L0 norm formulation? Is there any paper discussing the benefit of L0 (disregard the computational perspectives) over L1 norm compressed sensing?

**Edit**: The actual application we are interested in is about avoiding overfitting formulated below. For example $x$ is a very long feature vector (say length 1000), how ever we only 100 data, i.e., ${E_{feature}}$ is 100 by 1000, and ${E_{input}}$ is 100 by 1. The question we are interested in is whether the L0 norm formulation (if can be computed practically) can offer significant advantage over the L1 norm formulation.

$$\eqalign{
  & \min \quad \left\| {{E_{feature}}x - {E_{input}}} \right\|_2^2 + \mu {\left\| x \right\|_{0,1}}  \cr 
  & s.t:\quad Ax \le b \cr} $$

Comment: It depends. If your only goal is really just to look for the sparsest possible thing, then the L0 norm may be the way to go. On the other hand, sometimes when doing e.g. LASSO or BPDN type problems, we want to weight the vector so that not every element counts equally to the sparsity total; that is we want to minimize an expression like $\|y - Ax\|_2^2 + \|Wx\|_1$ for some weighting matrix $W$. You can think of this from a Bayesian/MAP viewpoint as kind of like putting an additional "prior" on the parameter vector in addition to just the sparsity prior (which is a Laplace distribution). (1/2)

Comment: If you want to do that kind of thing, then you could, I guess, try to do some kind of "weighted L0 norm," but sometimes the L1 norm formulation is useful in that it's kind of a relaxed version of sparsity that can be useful if large values are viewed as "less sparse" than small values, particularly if you want to weight things. One thing you could always do is to add some linear combination of the L1 and L0 norms, if you want. Or, if you want something in between the L0 and L1 norms, you can try using a Cauchy prior instead of the implicit Laplace distribution that you get w/ the L1 norm.